# How to populate data in drop down using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to populate pModel(50gm,100gm,250gm) in drop down using Angular JS

```
$scope.products=
{
"shopId" : "569df5c1d08598371e9b5ad5",
"mProId" : "569e07ccd08598371ebe5409",
"priceTag" : [
        {
            "pModel" : "50gm",
            "priceTagId" : 1,

        },
        {
            "pModel" : "100gm",
            "priceTagId" : 2,

        },
        {
            "pModel" : "250gm",
            "priceTagId" : 3,

        }
    ]
}
```

I am doing in this way.I dont know how it wont populate .Please help me to populate this one.
This is my code

```
<select class="form-control" id="pricetags" ng-model="selectedPriceTag" 
    ng-options="product.priceTag.pModel for product in products" > 
</select>
```

Comment: I am not clear if you are repeating product or price-tags.... if products then I think it should be `product.priceTag[0].pModel` and if you want product and then price tags as its child then you will have to use `group` syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/lP4bRfvtSZV6PQ2Uv4gR?p=info)

The problem is because you need to iterate through the `priceTag` property in products.

I recommend you update your code to the following

```
<select class="form-control" id="pricetags" ng-model="selectedPriceTag" 
ng-options="priceTag.pModel for priceTag in products.priceTag" > 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <select class="form-control" id="pricetags" ng-model="products.selectedPriceTag">
    <option ng-repeat="product in products.priceTag" value="{{product.priceTagId}}">{{product.pModel}}</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the ng-options syntax for arrays, but you're trying to select from $scope.products, an object.  Modify your code so it iterates through the priceTag array in the $scope.products object..

```
<select class="form-control" id="pricetags" ng-model="selectedPriceTag" 
ng-options="priceTag.pModel for priceTag in products.priceTag" > 
</select>
```

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but it should work!